# Libwebsockets returning 406 error for css and js files

Tags: libwebsockets

I'm trying to add css files `/usr/local/share/libwebsockets-test-server/`

but for some reason, I'm getting `406 Not Acceptable` error.

I have checked the permission and both `test.html` and the css file inside `css` directory have `644` permission and both belong to `root`.

FWIW, CDN for `jquery` seems to work fine.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In libwebsockets\test-server\test-server-http.c there are some lines:

```
#if 1
    /* this example server has no concept of directories */
    if (strchr((const char *)in + 1, '/')) {
        lws_return_http_status(wsi, HTTP_STATUS_NOT_ACCEPTABLE, NULL);
        goto try_to_reuse;
    }
#endif
```

Change the '#if 1' to '#if 0' and rebuild. See if that fixes the issue.
It did for me. I assume that complicated dir layouts don't work well. But it could follow my dir structure fine.

Comment: Thanks.

But,  for me (IIRC), I had to add some lines in lib/server.c (or some other file) to *handle* the javascript file. And it worked.


Edit: Remove code, apparently the formatting thingy doesn't work in comment replies. haha